# Can't access my Heroku repo even though I've added my key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm trying to clone a current project from Heroku. I was having permission access issues so I removed existing keys, and added my current key:

```
$ heroku keys:add

Found an SSH public key at /home/martyn/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Would you like to upload it to Heroku? [Yn] Y
Uploading SSH public key /home/martyn/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... done

$ heroku keys

=== martynbissett@yahoo.co.uk Keys
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...5VRkk6UVBT martyn@martyn-Lenovo-B590

$ heroku git:clone -a young-lowlands-8336

Cloning from app 'young-lowlands-8336'...
Cloning into 'young-lowlands-8336'...
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've check the site is live, and it is. From my Heroku control panel I can see that this project is active too. Why am I still being denied?

Comment: Are you the owner of this app? You can check it in your dashboard: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/young-lowlands-8336/access

Comment: Yes I am the owner of this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the response I got back from Heroku, and it seems to work now:

It looks like your local SSH is using a different key than the default one.
Could you try resetting your keys identities to the default with the following command:

```
ssh-add -D
```